# CRM Online - Application Ribbon XML don't show complete RibbonDiff definitions

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm, microsoft-dynamics

I am new to CRM online. I am trying to add a button on the ribbon. To help with that, i initially tried using Visual Ribbon Editor; But when i exported the solution, the RibbonDiff didn't show me complete set of entity ribbons. So i tried to directly export the application ribbon from CRM online. For this i followed the standard process - a) created new solution b) used 'Add Exiting' and added the application ribbon c) exported the solution. When i opened the 'Customisation' xml, it doesn't show me the complete RibbonDiff definitions. I am missing something here?

Thanks,
Vijay

Answer (score 2):

When you export any customization it will only contains the differences from the standard ribbon definition.

You can find the complete ribbon definition inside the SDK, the exact folder is

```
resources\exportedribbonxml
```

However to create a new button (and not editing an existing one) isn't necessary to have the complete ribbon definition, just follow this tutorial

https://community.dynamics.com/crm/b/lostinthoughtsofcrm/archive/2013/01/18/microsoft-dynamics-crm-2011-adding-a-new-custom-ribbon-button.aspx

or use another tool, as Ribbon Workbench for Dynamics CRM 2011 by Scott Durow

http://www.develop1.net/public/page/Ribbon-Workbench-for-Dynamics-CRM-2011.aspx